# Javascript: Why do I put "()" after a variable when calling it in console.log?

Tags: javascript

I'm working through examples in the ebook "eloquent javascript." On page 51, in the Functions chapter, in the Closure section, there's the following example:

```
function wrapValue2(n) {

  var localVariable = n; 
    return function() {
       return localVariable; 
  };
}

 var wrap2 = wrapValue2(3);
   console.log(wrap2());
```

As you can see in the last line of the code above, "console.log(wrap2());," the variable is being called inside of console.log. I was having some trouble re-writing this code until I realized there are parenthesis after the variable! Why would I put parenthesis after a variable?

Don't I only do that after a function?

Is this command using the variable as a function? If so, why?

Is it because the object contained within the variable is a function? That doesn't seem very likely.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you only put parenthesis after a function.

Comment: `wrap2` is not a mere variable, it's a function.

Comment: `wrapValue2(n)` returns a function as well, not a value. so you can do `wrap2()`

Comment: What do you think `return function` means?

Comment: It's a functional programming example. `wrapValue2` returns a function

Comment: `console.log(typeof wrap2);`

Comment: wrapValue2 is obviously a function...
wrap2 is a variable that contains an instance of a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly: those parentheses are used to call `wrap2`, because it's a function.

You use

```
var wrap2 = wrapValue2(3);
```

And the function `wrapValue2` returns another function.

So `wrap2` is a function.

Comment: so when I want to call a variable containing a function I must terminate it with "()"

this means that javascript treats variables containing functions as though they are functions themselves, correct?

Thanks for confirming that for me.

Comment: @AndÚ If you meant if a function declaration and a function expression are same: yes, the behave almost identically (the only difference is that function expressions are hoisted to the top of the scope). See [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/1529630).

Comment: I started looking through the many tutorials offered on the thread you linked to in the comment above, useful! Though while reading through the [4th of example of the "Function As Object" section of permandi tutorial](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/jsFunc/index.htm) I noticed yet another nuance that requires clarification. var ptr=myFunction"A function is referenced inside of a variable without its parenthesis! So, is the rule, then, I use parenthesis when I call a function-containing variable inside of a command, but no parenthesis are needed when defining a function-containing variable?

Answer (score 0):

The function ...

```
function wrapValue2(n) {
  var localVariable = n; 
    return function() {
       return localVariable; 
  };
}
```

returns a function (see `return function()`) ... that will need executed to get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because `wrap2` will be  function as at the end `wrapValue2` returns a `function` not a `value`.